# Google Maps Launch the Application

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

When I push the button, how will I be able to launch the Google application? My application crashes when I launch it. I'm working with Kotlin. Below is the sample of the code. I am not sure if my code is correct or the xml file.  Thank you

```
        launch_button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
    launch_button.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(view: View?){
            val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=22.659239,88.435534&mode=1"))
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
            if(mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                startActivity(mapIntent)
            }


        }
    })
```

This is my XML code;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Navigation"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#359c5e"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Hi"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps you have not added maps api key in your project. that's why it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is next chunk of code

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:22.659239,88.435534");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
  startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

This is an example from official documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#intent_requests

Let me know if that resolves, or provide a stack trace if not

Comment: Thank you. I have attached my XML file. I think I have an incorrect XML code because when I removed my kotlin chunk of code it still didnt work. It keeps on crashing. Thank you

Comment: could you please attach exception you are getting?

Comment: Sorry but where can I find exception? It only said build successfully. Thank you..

Comment: In the original message it's stated that the app is crashing. Please, provide the stacktrace for the crash